# Chrome: click madness when using input date inside anchor

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to have an `<input type="date"/>` inside an anchor because I want my list items to be clickable. Consider:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="container list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://google.com"><input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /> bla bla bla</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://google.com"><input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /> bla bla bla</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://google.com"><input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /> bla bla bla</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://google.com"><input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /> bla bla bla</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://google.com"><input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /> bla bla bla</a>
</ul>
</body>

<script>
    $('input').click(function(ev) {
        //return false;
        //ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvatd8f1/

My problem is that to avoid clicks propagating to the anchor, I need to stop the event propagation. But, at least in my Chromium 51, the input date arrow which shows the calendar (in the right of the field) stops working.

(The code is using bootstrap, but it is not relevant. The issue can be easily replicated without it.)

Suggestions? :)

By the way, I just recently realized that `<input type="date"/>` is Chrome-specific. We will very likely want to change this in the product. But, for now, since it is only a prototype to show the client, if there is a simple way to workaround this, it would be great. :)

Comment: I guess Chrome doesn't open the date selector because you stop the default behaviour. stopPropagation works for me.

Nevermind - it doesn't work when clicking on the selecting date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the easiest solution is to not use a tags but a simple li and change the url via JS:

```
<li data-href="https://google.com">...</li>

$(".container li").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).data("href")
})
```

Comment: Hmmm. Very elegant workaround! I will give it a try, and then come back to you. :)